# HTML5 sound adds top margin space on iphone

Tags: iphone, html

this is simple html5 page but when i display it on iphone top margin space appears

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = UTF-8 />
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi = device-dpi,width=device-width,content=user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var audio = document.createElement("audio");
            document.body.appendChild(audio);
            var c = document.createElement("canvas");
            c.width = 320;
            c.height = 480;
            c.style.background = "blue";
            document.body.appendChild(c);;

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0"></body>
```

what is the reason for that and how can i remove this top margin 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

this problem doesn't exist android and samsung bada i found a solution just like this

```
audio.style.display = "absolute";
audio.zindex = "-1";
```

now the audio element is behind the canvas element and it work as i want